# No such file or directory when trying to read from path

Tags: android, retrofit

> 

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("file/*");
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setType("video/*");
                      //  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE)
 if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
            // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
            // provided to this method as a parameter.
            // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
            Uri uri = null;

            if (resultData != null) {
                uri = resultData.getData();
                uri1 = uri;
                Log.i("anderwidth", "Uri: " + uri.toString());
File file = new File(uri1.getPath());
            }
        }
```

I am using retrofit with android. thats what happening? I cannot get to read the images and videos as files,  file.exists give me false.Everytime its content//...

it works if someone downloaded filemanager app, not if not downloaded.

Comment: `File file = new File(uri1.getPath());`. That will not work. Please post complete value of uri1.getPath() and uri2.toString().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'read' from path then open an InputStream and read() from the stream.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Comment: how can i turn that to a file? because i need to upload a file?

Comment: Well what would you do if you had a file system path and had opened a FileInputStream? You would read() the bytes from that stream. Well if you did it yourself. If you use a library then let the library use the uri.